# Run method every hour

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, arduino-uno-wifi, task

I have a method. I need to trigger it every hour (cron job).

I mean:

10.00 p.m -> Trigger

11.00 p.m -> Trigger

12.00 p.m ->Trigger

...

...

Card: Arduino Uno + Wifi Shield.

**Draft Code**

```
  void setup() {

  }
  
  void onTimeChanged() {
      runTask();
  }
  
  void loop() {
     
  }
  
  
  /*run this method when:
  13.00 p.m
  14.00 p.m
  15.00 p.m
  ........
  ........    */
  void runTask() {

  }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Wild guess: do you want an Arduino to connect to a server when the timezone the travelling Arduino is in changes?

Comment: Do you want the Arduino to determine in what timezone it is (by IP or GPS geolocation) or do you want the Arduino to determine when local Daylight Saving Time starts or ends? There are libraries available for both.

Comment: I just want to make cron jobs. Such as; 10.00 pm,11.00 pm, 12.00pm -> Execute Method

Comment: It is not confusing anymore. I edited question.

Comment: Do you need the task to trigger at the exact hour (xx:00, full hour with zero minutes), or do you only care about the _period_ being one hour (like at 10:23, 11:23, 12:23, 13:23...). In the former case, do you have an RTC? A GPS receiver? A WiFi module?

Comment: I need to trigger at the **exact** hour. I don't have any of them. If needed, i can buy them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Arduino Uno doesn't have a *Real Time Clock*, but you could contact a **NTP time server** on the internet using the WiFi shield you mention, and get the time from there, and then keep track of time using `millis()`. Every so often, you should adjust the time with a new call to the NTP time server, because the Arduino's clock isn't all that accurate.

The easiest way would be to get a **RTC module** (I think the most accurate and still affordable at the moment are [DS3231](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf)-based). They have a slot for a backup battery so they keep time even when there is no power supply.

Connect the module using I<sup>2</sup>C to your Arduino, install the appropriate library, and ask it every second (or however accurate you want to be) in your `loop()` for the exact time.

These modules usually also have an interrupt pin and can generate an interrupt when an alarm time is reached; you could use that also.

Comment: FWIW, [RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) supports alarms only [with the DS3231](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___d_s3231.html). A [pull request](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/pull/212) is in progress to add support for the alarms of the PCF8563. There may be other RTC/library alternatives though.